# "Updating search indexes" message in admin sidebar

Tags: search

I'm noticing the following error in my admin sidebar:

[image]

If I try to retry it just fails again. I can't see anything obviously failing in my logs. I'm not sure if this is related to the queue, but if I look at my queue info I see a failed job:

```
$> ./craft queue/info
Jobs
- waiting: 0
- delayed: 0
- reserved: 0
- failed: 1
```

[The Craft docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/searching.html#rebuilding-your-search-indexes) mention the ability to rebuild the search index manually:

> Craft does its best to keep its search indexes as up-to-date as possible, but there are a couple things that might render portions of them inaccurate. If you suspect that your search indexes don’t have the latest and greatest data, you can have Craft rebuild them with the Rebuild Search Indexes tool in Settings.

But looking at this Github issue:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3698

It appears that this option has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on Craft 3.2+, the Update Asset Indexes Utility has been removed in favor of the `craft resave` console command, which will update the search indexes as a side-effect of re-saving the element and it gives you much more fine-grained control over which elements/search indexes to resave.

Will update the docs you linked to reflect that.

To debug your failed job in the queue, I'd start by searching the `queue.log` file in the Craft logs folder for the underlying error message.